# Peering in Azure - 2nd subscription "not found in tenant"

Tags: azure, powershell, jenkins, cloud

When I try to use Powershell to make a peering link in Azure, between vnets in different subscriptions but in the same tenant, I get the following error messages.

Without specifying tenant:

> Set-AzureRmContext : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.

So I tried specifying the tenant:

> Get-AzureRmSubscription : Subscription was not found in tenant ****. Please verify that the subscription exists in this tenant.

I'm using Jenkins with a root account that has access to the dev subscription. I'm setting those credentials using the Microsoft Azure Service Principal bindings, before the job is run.

Does anyone know how I can code my Powershell script so that the Azure end recognises the 2nd subscription ID that I'm trying to peer to?

Current code below.

```
Write-Host "Create Vnet Peering from dev-vnet to test-centralhub-vnet"

$Subscription1 = Get-AzureRmSubscription -TenantId '(sanitised for Stackoverflow)' -SubscriptionId '(sanitised for Stackoverflow)'
Set-AzureRmContext -Subscription $subscription1
$Vnet1 = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -name 'test-centralhub-vnet' -ResourceGroupName 'test-networks-hub-rg'

$Subscription2 = Get-AzureRmSubscription -TenantId '(sanitised for Stackoverflow)' -SubscriptionId '(sanitised for Stackoverflow)'
Set-AzureRmContext -Subscription $Subscription2
$Vnet2 = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -name 'dev-vnet' -ResourceGroupName 'networks-dev-rg'

Set-AzureRmContext -Subscription '(sanitised for Stackoverflow)'
Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkPeering -Name 'dev-vnet_to_test-centralhub-vnet' -VirtualNetwork $Vnet2 -RemoteVirtualNetworkId $Vnet1.ID -UseRemoteGateways
```

Comment: Usually, that error indicates you don't have rights to that subscription. Are you sure you have access to both subs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment points out, the account you log in with must have the necessary permissions to create a virtual network peering. You can peer virtual networks that exist in two different subscriptions as long as a privileged user of both subscriptions authorizes the peering and the subscriptions are associated with the same Active Directory tenant.

For a list of permissions, see [Virtual network peering permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-peering#permissions).

I just test this on my local Powershell. My account was assigned a `contributor` role in another subscription level, then run your Powershell scripts with the same account successfully.

If you create peering with a different account in the different subscription. You may log in to Azure by entering the [Connect-AzureRmAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/connect-azurermaccount?view=azurermps-6.13.0#examples) command for each subscription. More details from [Create peering - PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-peering-different-subscriptions#powershell). Note, the linking scripts are using new `Az` module. You can refer it to replace `Az` with `AzureRm` for `AzureRm` module.

[image]

Comment: From what I can tell this appears to be correct. I'll need to discuss this with the security engineer responsible for setting up the permissions, as I can't change them myself. Thanks.